# Vectorize Cublic Spline interpolation Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I have the following function which I am trying to perform over a whole set of data.

```
def spln_inter_curve2(x,y,x_new):
    f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y,kind='cubic')
    return f(x_new)
```

I want to be able to pass  x and y as arrays shape (1892,15)
and  return and interpolated  array with shape (1892,22) (Shape of x_new). Each row of the interpolated array represents each row of x and y.

if I pass the arrays to the function I get the following error:

*ValueError: x and y arrays must be equal in length along interpolation axis.*

This Works:

y_new= spln_inter_curve2(x[1000],y[1000],xnew[1000])

I get the correct interpolated data for that row:

array([4.57      , 4.43      , 4.33      , 4.31      , 4.38      ,
4.29      , 4.29621659, 4.39      , 4.46193642, 4.51      ,
4.54799165, 4.59      , 4.64386699, 4.7       , 4.74708955,
4.79      , 4.8326029 , 4.87      , 4.89558681, 4.92      ,
4.95454998, 5.015     ])

This gives me the  error mentioned above:

y_new= spln_inter_curve2(x,y,xnew)

I suppose I can use the a (apply,lamda) combination but I was wondering if there was another interpolation function that would allow me to do this.

For now after trying many different things and getting a bit frustrated I settled on this:

```
y_new= np.array([spln_inter_curve2(x[x],y[x],xnew[x]) for x in range(0,len(swaps))])
```

It works fine and since the arrays are not that large its quick enough. I am sure there must be  a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `axis` argument to select the axis of y. But the x array needs to be 1D (and have the length compatible with the interpolation axis of y)